# How can I skip the tutorial?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I am trying out the Rogue Legacy **demo**. I do understand that the objective is to have succeeding generations to slowly build up strength - but when my initial character dies a miserable death in penury, I just want to restart the game.

Using the Delete Save option in the menu, the new character always has to suffer through an introduction and even a mini tutorial level. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can skip the tutorial by pausing and selecting the "Quit to Title" option, which is also helpfully labeled "Skip Tutorial" during the tutorial. This will allow you to immediately start the game from the meaningful bits.

Comment: I do not know whether the demo shares this feature, but it's useful information regardless.

Comment: I can't believe i haven't noticed that before. But you are right, tutorial can be skiped, and i just installed demo to test and it's skipable there too. Intro itself doesn't seem to be skipable however.